# нужна одна строка с дубликата в SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Всем привет,

У меня есть таблица и мне с нее нужна только одна запись, даже если у этой записи есть дубликат.
Как это можно написать в SQL? Спасибо заранее

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

SELECT UniCode, CmpUnicode2, CmpUnicode1 
FROM test_table tt 
JOIN yt_unicode yu ON yu.CmpUnicode1 = tt.CmpUnicode1 HAVING count(*) = 1

Comment: Мне нужна, например 4 строка. Проблема в том что я делаю join на данные которые приходят с CmpUnicode1

Comment: SELECT UniCode, CmpUnicode2, CmpUnicode1
FROM test_table tt
JOIN yt_unicode yu
ON yu.CmpUnicode1 = tt.CmpUnicode1
HAVING count(*) = 1

Comment: Мне нужна в этом случаи только одна запись, например 4

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT min(UniCode), min(CmpUnicode2), tt.CmpUnicode1 
FROM test_table tt JOIN yt_unicode yu ON yu.CmpUnicode1 = tt.CmpUnicode1 
group by tt.CmpUnicode1
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно добавить условие LIMIT 3,1 где 3 означает что будет начат показ с 4-й строки, а 1 означает что будет выведена 1 запись...

```
SELECT UniCode, CmpUnicode2, CmpUnicode1 
FROM test_table tt 
JOIN yt_unicode yu 
ON yu.CmpUnicode1 = tt.CmpUnicode1 HAVING count(*) = 1 
LIMIT 3,1;
```

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Comment: Им помогаешь а они еще и минусы ставят, отморозки какие-то:

Comment: Я минусы не ставил не каму!

Comment: Я плюсанул, что бы в не огорчались)

Comment: Плюсы минус.... проблема то осталась...:(

Comment: А что выводит когда вы добавляете LIMIT?

Comment: LIMIT выведет мне эту строку, но проблема у меня таких записей штук 500.

Comment: А так вам надо просто вывести записи без дубликатов... Вы бы так и написали... SELECT UniCode, CmpUnicode2, CmpUnicode1 FROM test_table tt JOIN yt_unicode yu ON yu.CmpUnicode1 = tt.CmpUnicode1 HAVING count(*) = 1 GROUP BY tt.CmpUnicode1; внизу ответ вам правильно написали... В самом конце пишим GROUP BY и после него столбец по которому выявляем  дубликаты